# How to update data for all users with a button on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

I have my index view with some code :

So i have my User model. Each user has a column "readyy". 
If its = 0, so I display "Ready", = 1 "not ready", =2 "Unconfirmed"
Each user can edit its own state, and admins can edit all users state one by one.

But how can I display a button (only for admin with my "current_user.admin?" method) that set the readyy cell to 2 (to set all users "unconfirmed") for all users ? Like, all in the same time.
NowI have to click one by one to set the readyy state to 2, it's not convenient.
Here is my view erb :

```
<% @user.each do |u| %>

<div class="<% if u.readyy == 2 %>unconfirmed <% end %> <% if u.readyy == 1 %>ready<% end %> <% if u.readyy == 0 %> not_ready<% end %>">

<%= u.name %>

<% if current_user %>
<% if current_user.id == u.id || current_user.admin? %>

<%= form_with(model: u) do |form| %>


<%= form.submit 'UPDATE STATE' %>

<% if current_user.admin? %>

<%= form.select :readyy, @readyyy # @readyyy = {  unconfirmed: 2, ready: 1, not_ready: 0 } %>

<% else %>

<%= form.select :readyy, @readyy #@readyy = {  ready: 1, not_ready: 0 } %>

<%end %>

<%end %>
<%end %>
<%end %>
<%end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you look at the aasm gem for state management: https://github.com/aasm/aasm. This should work :

markup:

```
<%= button_to "Unconfirm users", unconfirm_all_users, method: :patch %>
```

routes:

```
resources :users do
  patch :unconfirm_all, on: :collection
end
```

controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def unconfirm_all
    User.update_all(ready: 2)
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for you answer, I tried it but when I access the view it return me an error :
'
Showing /home/otho/code/othocore/othocore/app/views/users/index.html.erb where line #3 raised:

undefined local variable or method `unconfirm_all_users' for #<#<Class:0x007febfc1111e8>:0x007fec01cf2f70>
Did you mean?  unconfirm_all_users_url
               unconfirm_all_users_path'

Comment: Added _path to unconfirm_all_users and worked ! Thanks u !!